# github not rendering jupyter notebook python

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

I am facing a very strange issue, and I hope someone can help me. I am working with Jupyter notebooks in Python. The notebooks works fine locally and were rendering perfectly on github until last week. Suddently it seems I cannot see most of the notebooks on github anymore. I always get hte error "Something went wrong. Reload?". I can see some, and some don't render. Anyone any idea? The notebooks that are not working are in a private repository...

Take for example this notebook

https://github.com/michelucci/Sandbox/blob/master/Logistic%20Regression%20Part%201.ipynb

it was working before (at least rendering)

Thanks, Umberto

Comment: I would sugget : 1- re upload the project, maybe there is some bug associated with the file on github. 2- Check the version of the jupyter version used there.

Comment: I see there's an image in the output of one of the cells. It could be having trouble rendering it. Maybe clear output before uploading them?

Comment: Looking at the github source, the error being returned is simply: "Sorry, this file is invalid so it cannot be displayed". But it renders fine using the nbviewer at https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/, so doesn't seem like a bug with your file. Would seem to be a github issue.

Answer (score 3):

I actually asked the github team and they informed that it was an issue from their side. Is now working. So something just waiting helps.
Thanks everyone, Umberto

Comment: As of today, your page, that you linked above, is still not working. The message ``Something went wrong. Reload?'' still appear

Answer (score 0):

Solved here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6507

The bug happens because the code blocks from Colab are missing "outputs':[] and "execution_count":null.

```
{
    "cell_type": "code",
    "metadata": {
     "id": "e2769b9e0005"
   },
    "source": [
      "!pip install git+https://github.com/google/starthinker\n"
    ]
  },
```

To fix add the missing fields to the colab source for any code block only not markdown:

```
{
    "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": null,
    "outputs": [],
    "metadata": {
      "id": "e2769b9e0005"
    },
    "source": [
      "!pip install git+https://github.com/google/starthinker\n"
    ]
 },
```